# Is it wrong to say ''Get out your books''?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

1) When we are in class, is it wrong to say ''get out your books'' to the students? 
Should it be ''get your books out''? 
Is there a difference? Or is it ''take out your books / take your books out''? Are these separable phrasal verbs?

2) Is it incorrect to say 'what page'? I know we have been taught 'which page are we'' but ''what page are on'' sounds also natural to me?

thank you

Comment: "Get out your books" is normal. "What page?" is normal.

Comment: You are on the wrong site. Try English Language Learners.

Comment: Depends on your local idiom; depends on if you are an English teacher; depends on if English is the pupils' native tongue.

Comment: Technically though, you critic(s) must be right, if only a bit pedantic.

Comment: (1) Both are equally acceptable; "Get your books out" probably lends itself better to emphasis. // (2) Only a pedant would quibble about either usage here.